# Как сохранить изображение сгенерированое php?

Tags: php, изображения

Получаю изображения такого вида

```
http://site.ru/image.php?seller_id=39330&vehicle_id=4932693&orig=1&image=1&rand=19122012023653
```

Но мне нужно сохранить их к себе на сервер.
Не могу придумать как это сделать средствами php.

Comment: >Не могу придумать как это сделать средствами php

А как уже думал?

Comment: Хотело курлом, но не вышло

Comment: cURL'ом — правильное намерение. Что не вышло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   // Получаем содержимое файла с другого сервера 
      $content = file_get_contents("http://site.ru/image.php?seller_id=39330&vehicle_id=4932693&orig=1&image=1&rand=19122012023653");
      // Записать полученное содержимое в файл image.png
      file_put_contents("image.png",$content);
```

А вообще в гугле море примеров... " Это самый примитивный, без проверки расширений файла, ну а дальше думаю уже все понятно!